# Hibernate mapping map two columns with other table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 table one is Order and other is OrderList.

*Order table* is having following fields

**customerId** : foreign key to customer table

**applicationId** : foreing key to application table

**OrderedAt**

**OrderedOn**

*OrderList table* has to refer order table using applicationId and customerId and having fields:

**customerId**: foreing key to Order table\

**applicationId**: foreing key to Order table

**OrderItem**

**Orderprice**

I want to map these two in hibernate.xml file

I am not making a seperate file for OrderList.hibernate.xml:

but using below code in Order.hibernate.xml itself

```
<list name="orders" table="Order_List" cascade="all" access="field">
            <key column="applicationId" not-null="true"/>
            <key column="customerId" not-null="true"/>
            <list-index column="OrderListIndex" />
            <composite-element class="OrderList">
                
                <property name="OrderItem" />
                <property name="OrderPrice" />
            </composite-element>
        </list>
```

Am I using the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me, though you should switch to using JPA annotations as hbm.xml mappings are deprecated in the latest Hibernate versions and will go away at some point. Also, a lot more people can help you with the annotation model, so you would get answers faster.